# Select tableview row programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How do I programmatically select a `UITableView` row so that

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

gets executed? `selectRowAtIndexPath` will only highlight the row.

Comment: I encountered the same issue and just fine the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324501/select-tableviews-row-from-an-another-view I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

From [reference documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrowatindexpath?language=objc)

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message, nor does it send `UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` notifications to observers.

What I would do is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self doSomethingWithRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

And then, from where you wanted to call selectRowAtIndexPath, you instead call doSomethingWithRowAtIndexPath. On top of that, you can additionally also call selectRowAtIndexPath if you want the UI feedback to happen.

Comment: Or when you select the row programmatically, you could call tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: yourself (in the class you have wired as the delegate).

Comment: This method seems like a hack to me , it did get the job done but i think there should be a better way of doing it .

Comment: I don't really think you need to create a call "doSomethingWithRowAtIndexPath"  can't you just call the delegate method and pass the arguments you need to execute the didSelect logic from the place where you implemented the delegate method?

Answer (score 120):

Like Jaanus told:

> Calling this (-selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:) method
>   does not cause the delegate to receive a
>   tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: or
>   tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: message, nor will it send
>   UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification notifications to observers.

So you just have to call the `delegate` method yourself.

For example:

Swift 3 version:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0);
self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

ObjectiveC version:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                            animated:YES 
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Swift 2.3 version:

```
 let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0);
 self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
 self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 63):

UITableView's [selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW11) should do the trick.

Just pass `UITableViewScrollPositionNone` for scrollPosition and the user won't see any movement.

---

You should also be able to manually run the action:

`[theTableView.delegate tableView:theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

after you `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` so the highlight happens as well as any associated logic.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I'm using.  I accidentally put scrollToRowAtIndexPath. I've updated the question. scrollToRowAtIndexPath only highlights the cell.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. It says it won't fire didSelectRowAtIndexPath right there in the docs link I posted. I need to learn to read.

Comment: @anq: Thank you very much! It helps me when I call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath in the custom cell.

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 3/4/5 Solution**

***Select Row***

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
tblView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
myTableView.delegate?.tableView!(myTableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

***DeSelect Row***

```
let deselectIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 7, section: 0)
tblView.deselectRow(at: deselectIndexPath, animated: true)
tblView.delegate?.tableView!(tblView, didDeselectRowAt: indexPath)
```

Comment: For me, adding '.delegate?' was the key. (Swift 4.5)

Answer (score 21):

if you want to select some row this will help you

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[someTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                           animated:NO 
                     scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

This will also Highlighted the row.
Then delegate

```
 [someTableView.delegate someTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two different methods for iPad and iPhone platforms, so you need to implement both:

- selection handler and
- segue.

  ```
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
  [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

  // Selection handler (for horizontal iPad)
  [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  // Segue (for iPhone and vertical iPad)
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:"showDetail" sender:self];
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Use this category to select a table row and execute a given segue after a delay.
Call this within your `viewDidAppear` method:

```
[tableViewController delayedSelection:withSegueIdentifier:]


@implementation UITableViewController (TLUtils)

-(void)delayedSelection:(NSIndexPath *)idxPath withSegueIdentifier:(NSString *)segueID {
    if (!idxPath) idxPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];                                                                                                                                                                 
    [self performSelector:@selector(selectIndexPath:) withObject:@{@"NSIndexPath": idxPath, @"UIStoryboardSegue": segueID } afterDelay:0];                                                                                               
}

-(void)selectIndexPath:(NSDictionary *)args {
    NSIndexPath *idxPath = args[@"NSIndexPath"];                                                                                                                                                                                         
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:idxPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];                                                                                                                            

    if ([self.tableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)])
        [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:idxPath];                                                                                                                                              

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:args[@"UIStoryboardSegue"] sender:self];                                                                                                                                                            
}

@end
```

Comment: The question had nothing to do with segues.

Comment: Yes, about nothing in your answer is related to the question

Comment: Appreciate this answer. This works perfectly if the user wants to achieve the same behaviour but is using storyboards.