# indexpath.row returns random in-range number on didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a program, a main view with a sub-nib. Inside that nib is a perfectly-loaded table with data that was archived.

I've released a product already using table views, read the manuals, know how they work (mostly)... StackOverflow exists for a reason...

Now I kept selecting out of range errors, so I shoved this: 
[NSLog... indexPath.row )] and noticed, every time I select a new cell, it's practically random. If I select a cell 2 away from a cell, I get this 0, 2, 0, 2 pattern. If I go one away, it's one selection different. But it's as if their values slowly change. The data doesn't, but cell 3 returns all 5 numbers as row 0-4 depending on how varied my clicks are (in the simulator).

I probably have another issue as it accesses an array, and crashes when I try to add or remove objects at the index (which was working fine before).

I will reboot the PC and uninstall the simulator's app and reinstall (data gets corrupted quite often just using the keyed archiver when developing), but thought I'd ask if anyone knows why this would happen.

Asking Apple for help usually results in "Do you know how to program? Read the manual again!" and I'm tired of being treated like I haven't coded for 10 years because they're too lazy to document important stuff.

Thank you! If I missed something and this has been asked, link me please!

NC

Comment: Post the code that gives the random results.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed it's only returning the "last one you selected". The first time you click on it, it doesn't even call the method. I think this is directly related to animating/moving the frame, but I"m not too sure. I'll go find issues with "Not calling didselect on first"... that's probably more related

Comment: Sorry, I would if I could. I found out i typed didDeselect, gah... thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305781/iphone-didselectrowatindexpath-not-invoked this one. Thanks for the response! Now, I gotta figure out why it's out of range... heh, not out completely. I can handle that part though.