# didSelectRowAtIndexPath event not triggered when select row programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I would like to select a cell in a tableView. It is working properly using this code, but once selected programmatically it does not trigger a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` event. How can I trigger it?

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.mainTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is working as documented:

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message, nor will it send `UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` notifications to observers.

Call it yourself after selecting your cell:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[self tableView:self.mainTable willSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.mainTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[self tableView:self.mainTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: For future travelers: This is a great explanation of why this doesn't work, but I believe this is a more comprehensive solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305781/iphone-didselectrowatindexpath-not-invoked