# Swift - selectRowAtIndexPath not working with indexPathForSelectedRows

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, multipleselection

When I use `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()`, calling `selectRowAtIndexPath` works perfectly. However, I am selecting multiple rows thus I am trying to use `table.View.indexPathForSelectedRows() as [NSIndexPath]`

<s>`Swift Compiler Error: NSIndexPath is not a subtype of NSIndexPath`</s>

**Error has been resolved.**

***Edit*** Added For Loop,  multiple selection still not happening.

```
//I initialized saveSelection globally
var saveSelection : [NSIndexPath]?



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{   
    saveSelection = (drugTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as [NSIndexPath])   
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    if !selectedDrugs.isEmpty
    {
        for save : NSIndexPath in saveSelection! as [NSIndexPath]
        {

            self.drugTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(save, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `saveSelection` is an array of `NSIndexPath`s, but `selectRowAtIndexPath` requires a single `NSIndexPath` as the first argument.

Comment: so there is no way to re-select multiple selections?

Comment: I didn't say that. I just said you can't insert an array into that function. Perhaps looping through the array and performing selectRowAtIndexPath on each of the NSIndexPaths will get you the result you want...

Comment: I was just trying that as you were typing... lol. trying to figure it out now. If you have any example code, that would be very helpful.  Thank you for responding

Comment: I added the for loop, but still no Luck

Comment: Yeah, the selectRowAtIndexPath line was a definite issue, but I suspected it might not be causing that particular error... Is the error specifically attached to the self.drugTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath line?

Comment: I apologize, I just edited the post. I no longer have the error. The `for loop` println's  successfully yet, it will not select the rows when I the return the the tableView.

Comment: I assume you were wanting `selectRowAtIndexPath` to result in a call to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`? Well, that's not automatic in this case and you'll have to do it manually. Here's a good answer explaining why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2726140/2274694

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

1. Made a dictionary of IndexPaths. Used `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` to add and remove key/value pairs to the dictionary.
2. Inside `viewWillAppear` I used `var indexForLoop = myDictionary.values.array` to as the indexPath set to pass into my `For Loop`
3. Crossed my fingers and hoped for the best

thank you Lyndsey for your help!