# select tableview's row from an another view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uibutton

I have made a TabViewController

In that there is a view with a table and a view with an Image and some buttons.

Now I want that when I press  button one of the view one the row one from the another view should be selected. and when I press button two...row two from the another view should be selected ..

can anyone tell me logically or with coding how to do this??

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a refernce to the second view - use answer by @Praveen.

If not, you can use Notifications, like this:

In View 'A':

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"selectRow" object:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rowNumber]]];
```

In View 'B':

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                           selector:@selector(selectRow:) name:@"selectRow" object:nil];

- (void) selectRow:(NSNotification*)n {
   NSNumber* row = [n object];
   NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[row intValue] inSection:0];
   [itemsTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
}
```

Comment: Hey Reflog...I am using your method...suppose I want to select 1st row ..so what should I write [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath: .... ];
 ?? Sorry to ask such a silly question..New bie here...:)

Comment: Reflog ...Perfect code..but i don't know buddy it's not happening..I am writing row number 1 which i want to select..but it is not getting selected..well let me put my code...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have reference to two views?

Direct method call using the views instance.

```
- (IBAction) view1ButtonPressed:(id)view1Button
{
  [view2 buttonPressedWithData]; // You can pass some data to view 2
}
```

There are other methods to do it also, basically if you have the reference to any object you can pass messages to it.