# Automatically cell selected UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

My UITableView opens via PopOverViewController , so How can I load one of these cells automatically after app did load ,

the cell selecting process on MainViewController

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {

    if (detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        [detailItem release];
        detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];

        //---update the view---
        label.text = [detailItem description];
    }

}
```

and cell selecting in TableViewController :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    myAppDelegate *appDelegate = 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.viewController.detailItem = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  

}
```

I use this code in TableViewController but does not work ! It means after press the the popOver button the code just highlight the cell !!

```
 [myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
```

I used above code in different methods like `viewDidAppear` , `viewWillAppear` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and ...

Thank you

Comment: If you expect that calling `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` will result in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` getting called, that is just not going to happen as per the documentation: "Calling this method -`selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`- does not cause the delegate to receive a `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message, nor will it send `UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` notifications to observers."

Comment: so is there any solution for that?

Comment: You could do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically/2035171#2035171) or call `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` yourself (on the delegate).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is **not** called on the delegate.

From the [selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:) reference:

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a
>   tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: or
>   tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: message, nor will it send
>   UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification notifications to observers.

So, instead of just calling `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`:

```
 [myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
```

you could call the delegate methods manually:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

if ([myTableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
    [myTableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];    

if ([myTableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
    [myTableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: thank you this code works fine ! but after my app did load , the label.text does not change ,until user press  the popOverView button

Comment: You update the label.text within `setDetailItem:`, which is called within `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, right? And now `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` does get called. So, my advise would be to check if some variable is nil (`list`?, `label`?, etc.) by the time `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` runs.

Comment: There is no any var as nill , unfortunately this is not which I was expect , the user must press the popOver button to change the label , and another problem is when users select different cells If they press the button again the label string back as CELL 0 !

Comment: Then I would suggest you to post a new question with the details of these other problems.