# Using Facebook "iOS native deep linking" and openURL with iOS 5 storyboard/segue based app?

Tags: ios5, uistoryboard, facebook-ios-sdk, uistoryboardsegue

I have an Facebook enabled, iOS 5 app that uses a storyboard and segue based navigation and am confused on how to implement "iOS native deep linking."  The example code at [Improving App Distribution on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/21/improving-app-distribution-on-ios/) just displays a `UIAlertView` but I am trying to initiate two consecutive seque operations.

For purposes of this question, I've simplified the application to three view controllers:  `MYCategoryTableViewController`, `MYItemsTableViewController` and `MYItemViewController`.  In the normal flow, the application opens to `MYCategoryTableViewController`, which displays a table of categories.  When a category is selected by the user, there is a segue to `MYItemsTableViewController` which displays a table of items for that selected category.  Lastly, when an item is selected, there is a segue to `MYItemViewController` which displays an item detail view.

The `prepareForSegue` from `MYCategoryTableViewController` sets a property on the destination view controller that represents that category:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ITEMS_SEGUE"]) {
        MYItemsTableViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];        
        MYCategory *mycategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
        vc.mycategory = mycategory;
    }
}
```

The `prepareForSegue` from `MYItemsTableViewController` sets a property on the destination view controller that represents that category:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ITEM_SEGUE"]) {
        MYItemViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        MYItem *myitem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
        vc.myitem = myitem;
    }
}
```

**Question:**  I know that I need to implement something in `application:openURL`, but not sure what to do next.  Assume the incoming URL gives identifiers to lookup the `MYCategory` and `MYItem` objects.  I found `performSegueWithIdentifier` but not sure how that interacts with `prepareForSegue` and how I set my model objects on the destination view controllers.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    // get "target_url" from incoming url
    // and parse out MYCategory and MYItem identifiers

    // something like this???
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ITEM_SEGUE" sender:self];

    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

**Update:** [Selecting programmatically a cell on a tableview doesn't perform associated segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104465/selecting-programmatically-a-cell-on-a-tableview-doesnt-perform-associated-segu) has given me an idea.  Maybe I just save off the url from `application:openURL:` and let `MYCategoryTableViewController` load naturally. Then during `viewWillAppear`, call `tableView selectRowAtIndexPath` and then `performSegueWithIdentifier` to transition to `MYItemsTableViewController`.  Repeat the same pattern in `MYItemsTableViewController`, but clear out the url before the `performSegueWithIdentifier` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I got working.  In `MYAppDelegate`, I captured a string represented the id of the deep link.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSString *deepLinkId;  
    // more code that parses url

    // only deep link if MYCategoryTableViewController is active controller
    UIViewController *rootContoller = self.window.rootViewController;
    if ([rootContoller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)rootContoller;
        if ([navController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MYCategoryTableViewController class]]) {
            self.deepLinkId = deepLinkId;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when `MYCategoryTableViewController` loads, call `selectRowAtIndexPath` and then `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

```
- (void)processDeepLink {  
    if (_appDelegate.deepLinkId) {
        MYItem *myitem = [MYItem lookupById:_appDelegate.deepLinkId inManagedObjectContext:_appDelegate.dataDocument.managedObjectContext];
        if (myitem) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:myitem.mycategory];
            [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ITEMS_SEGUE" sender:self];
        }
    }
}
```

And in when `MYItemViewController` loads, a similar flow.

```
if (_appDelegate.deepLinkId) {
    MYItem *plate = [MYItem lookupById:_appDelegate.deepLinkId inManagedObjectContext:_appDelegate.dataDocument.managedObjectContext];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:plate];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

    _appDelegate.deepLinkId = nil;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ITEM_SEGUE" sender:self];
}
```

I also had to observe `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` for the use case when the application was already open.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(processDeepLink)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```