# call didSelectRowAtIndexPath on button click from DetailView on iPad

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ipad

I am making an iPad SplitView App where I have the MasterView table on the left(in landscape orientation) and the DetailView on the right(nothing new so far...). When I click on a table cell, the detailView shows the cell details. 
I got also a button on the detialView to move forward to the next cell and a button to move backward to the previous cell.

My problem is that I would like to change the cell selection in the table view on the left every time I click on a button so the user knows on which cell he currently is.

I tried by calling the tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method but I can't seem to set the NSIndexPath right(I want to send an integer to indicate the number of the next cell).

Here is the code that's trzing to call the selectRowAtIndexPath: method:

iPadHelloWorldAppDelegate is the AppDelegate. masterViewController is the master controller with the table on it.

```
// method to set the image for the previous letter
-(IBAction)previousLetter{
    iPadHelloWorldAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSLog(@"IndexOfImage equals: %@", appDelegate.indexOfImage);

    int number = [[appDelegate.indexOfImage substringFromIndex:5] intValue];

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%@.png",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number-1]];
    [self.letterImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    NSLog(@"Image name: %@", imageName);

    appDelegate.indexOfImage = [imageName substringToIndex:6];       

    NSIndexPath *currentPath = appDelegate.currentPath;
    NSIndexPath *nextPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentPath.row-1 inSection:currentPath.section];

    [masterViewController.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:nextPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];    

    NSLog(@"currentPath: %@", currentPath);    
    appDelegate.currentPath = nextPath;        
    NSLog(@"nextPath: %@", nextPath);
```

Please help...

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically) is what your problem is addressed. Should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I tried that already and selectRowAtIndexPath will not even highlight the row like it did for the other guy. Which answer do you mean? The first with 'doSomeThing' method? didSelectRowAtIndex doesn't work for me neither...

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work. For your Forward Button use this code

```
NSIndexPath *currentPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSIndexPath *nextPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentPath.row+1 inSection:currentPath.section];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:nextPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

For the Back button, substitute -1 for +1.

See [NSIndexPath UIKit Additions documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) for the indexPathForRow:inSection:method.

Comment: HI! Thanks for the answer. I did what you wrote. I get the currentPath and can increase the nextPath now but it still doesn't select the cell.

Comment: Okay.  I had a typo in my last line (corrected), which you probably accounted for. If you can post your code in your original question (to show formatted code), that might help. Make sure you are referring to the tableView object by the right name. That's all I can think of without seeing some code.

Comment: This is a guess, because I haven't tried it, but you might try setting self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES; (Use the correct references to the tableView appropriate to your case.) If you are ini editing mode, you may need this, even if you are selecting cells programmatically.

Comment: I tried what zou suggested but it still doesn't change the cell row selection. I put some code in the initial question so u can see what I/m trzing to do...

Comment: I'm not sure why you set the cuurentPath = appDelegate.currentPath. It looks unusual that the application delegate would hold that as a property. I would suggest you follow my original recommendations and use NSIndexPath *currentPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
 or NSIndexPath *currentPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];  This assumes that tableView is an iVar or property within the same object as your previousLetter method.

Comment: I'm storing the currentPath in appDelegate as a global variable because I'm calling from the detailViewCotroller and the currentPath is set on the masterViewController. I get the currentPath written out in the NSLog part at the bottom so that works but still... I could try NSIndexPath *currentPath = [masterViewController.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; but is it not the same?

Comment: I wrote a new question since I couldn't find an answer that worked for me so check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872763/call-selectrowatindexpath-on-button-click-in-ipad-splitview

Answer (score 0):

the "tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" is a delegate method; you shouldn't be calling that directly. Instead, try calling "selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:"

Comment: can U tell me how to set the NSIndexPath for the selectRowAtIndexPath:? I can't seem to get that right.

Comment: Easiest way is [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]

Comment: Well, this is not working for me. Just nothing happens when I call "tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:".

Comment: the "tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" is a delegate method; you shouldn't be calling that directly. Instead, try calling "selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:"