# Programmatically 'Touch' UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I need to programmatically select a UITableViewCell, I have tried this:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [table selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

However, it only selects the cell visually and doesn't pick up on that selection in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` unless you actually tap the cell.

Any ideas, has anyone experienced this or have ideas to get around this or approach it differently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select tableview row programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By wanting it pressed, I'm guessing you just want to run the code in didSelectRow?

Whatever you have in your didSelectRow method, can't you put it in a seperate method of its own and just call it?

Answer (score 9):

Why not send a message to didSelectRowAtIndexPath after you've sent a message to selectRowAtIndexPath?  The code should look like this:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[table selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath 
                   animated:YES 
             scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[table.delegate tableView:table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath];
```

Comment: You already know the index path you want to select, so try this: [table.delegate tableView:table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath];

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass your UITableView it's possible to customize UIEvent that occurs on each TableViewCells.
Your controller will respond to Touch Events:

- touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

For each event you have a NSSET of touches and you can find your UitableViewCell
Exemple :

```
 - touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    for(UITouch *aTouch in touches){
        if(aTouch.view IsYourUiTableViewCell){
           NSLOG(@"TableViewCell press!");
        }
    }
  }
```