# Strange behavior after selecting cell by code

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I ran into some strange behaviour after I selected a cell using this code :

```
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];

CustomCell * cell = (CustomCell*)[_myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];
```

After this i couldn't select exactly this cell it just didn't respond and

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

was never called.

This wasn't called either:

```
-(void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

What i am doing wrong guys?

Comment: Read this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call both methods manually because manually cell selection does not call delegate method.

```
[cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];
[self tableView:_myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's documentation it is expected behavior that the methods you mention are never called after programmatically selecting a cell. More info is [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically).