# How to call the delegate method of UITableView manually?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a button that should call the delegate method of tableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

when that button is tapped.

Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: Check this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically

Comment: Create a method (somewhere) which is used by both that delegate method and that button action method, and use that instead of this hack.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

A button won't be able to automatically call that method because it has no concept of a table view or index path, but if you create your own method you can call that method directly

```
- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *path = //path for row you want to select
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self tableView:_myTbl didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:_rowNeeded inSection:_sectionNeeded];
//call method, like user selected needed cell

[_myTbl selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
// show selected cell in UI
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that when user press the button on your TableViewCell then you fire the Action what's happen when a cell is tapped , then you can do the following.

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method , add a Gesture Recogniser on your button. Like this ,

```
cell.myButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row ;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tap setDelegate:self];
[cell.myButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Here is the handleTap method

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Handle Tap method");
    NSLog(@"Row Index : %d" , recognizer.view.tag);
    int row_index = recognizer.view.tag ;

    // Perform your Action woth row_index
}
```

And don't forget to add  in your header file. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For select entire row in table view cell check boxes :

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

take "i" value as for loop