# Select TableViews row programatically from custom PrototypeCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I have a PrototypeCell with two buttons in it each button will segue to an other detailed view of the displayed item. When I touch a button in the cell, I set a `NSNumber` to the selected buttons index (1 or 2) and set the cell selected. The cell then changes its color to grey (highlighted), but the `UITableViews` delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` does not get called.

How do I do it the right way? Cant figure it out.

Here's my code so far:

Inside the UITableViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TwoButtonPrototypeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setupButtons];
    NSArray *array1 = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row * 2];
    NSArray *array2 = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row * 2 + 1];
    cell.identifier1 = [array1 objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.identifier2 = [array2 objectAtIndex:0];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TwoButtonPrototypeCell *cell = (TwoButtonPrototypeCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    identifier = cell.touchedButtonIdentifier;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetails" sender:self];
}
```

Inside the TwoButtonPrototypeCell

```
- (void)setupButtons {
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(touchedButton1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(touchedButton2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)touchedButton1 {
    touchedButtonIdentifier = identifier1;
    [self setSelected:YES animated:NO];
}

- (void)touchedButton2 {
    touchedButtonIdentifier = identifier2;
    [self setSelected:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select tableview row programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically)

Comment: Nope, sice I want to select the TableViews row from the cell and not from the TableViewcontroller. I cant acces the tabeView from the cell.

Comment: Maybe the title was not clear enough, I fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a protocol inside your cell, then in  `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` 
set the delegate

```
cell.delegate = self;
```

call the cells delegate method when the button is pressed, for example you have implemented this protocol method inside your tableViewController

```
    - (void)cellButtonWasPressed:(TwoButtonPrototypeCell*)cell {
        [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]];    

}
```

so basically inside your cell you do this:

```
- (void)touchedButton1 {
    touchedButtonIdentifier = identifier1;
    [self.delegate cellButtonWasPressed:self];
}
```