# swift tableview how to select all rows

Tags: swift, uitableview, button

I have Button in tableview I want when I press that button will select all cell rows, how to do that? I tried alot but I got nothing

I'm so confused how to make the button contact the cell

I've tried to make var like this

```
var x = false
```

then I do like

```
if( x == true ) { //Code }
```

and when you press the button it will be true

but I don't know in which func I should put this ? and I don't know how to select all rows

Could someone help me how to Select \ Deselect all rows in cell when pressing button in tableview.

Thank you so much!

Comment: if there's no func to select all, is there a way to change all rows background color when i press the button ?

Comment: Background color of entire view?

Comment: background for cell rows, the cell using other swift file and table view using another swift file the button in the tableview

Comment: on button action set a bool value , reload the tableView . so cellForRowAtIndexPath method will invoke, in this method u check condition with bool value and set cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var selectedUsernameArray : NSMutableArray = []
var username1Array : NSMutableArray = ["hel","dsf","fsdg"]//just a sample
```

Initially button name should be "Select all"

Button action :

```
 @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {

   if(sender.titleLabel?.text == "Select all")
    {
        selectedUsernameArray .addObjectsFromArray(username1Array as [AnyObject])
        sender.titleLabel?.text = "Deselect all"
    }
    else
   {
    selectedUsernameArray .removeAllObjects();
    sender.titleLabel?.text = "Select all"
    }

    self.tableView .reloadData()
}
```

tableview delegate

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    var ob: AnyObject = username1Array .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row);
    cell.textLabel?.text = ob as? String;
    if(selectedUsernameArray .containsObject(ob))
    {
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var isSelectAll = false; //global variable

isSelectAll = true;//on button action
self.tableView.reloadData()//on button action
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
if(isSelectAll==true)
{
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
}
else
{
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the rows background still white wont changing!

Comment: I did and i found the issue, please take a look, how can i just select all rows when i press the button instead of changing colors ?

Comment: Could you tell me how can i add contains array to other array?

Comment: selectedUsernameArray .addObjectsFromArray(username1Array as [AnyObject])

Answer (score 0):

In    cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITableViewCell *cell...

cell.accesoryType = isSelectAll ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Comment: thank you , What's that code ? Could you help me how to select all rows when i press the button ?

Comment: Call [tableView reloadData] when user taps the button, and the the cellForRowAtIndexPath: will be called automatically.

Comment: Could you tell me how can i add contains array to other array?

Comment: NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:otherArray];

Comment: i'm using swift isn't objective-c, or how can i get all usernames in the rows and add them to array? when i press the button!

Comment: var newArray = Array<AnyObject>()
for x in oldArray {
    newArray.append(x)
}