# How to select all table view rows and get id of all rows using json parsing?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, tableview

I am creating `Swift` app and I have to select all `UITableView` rows on one button click. I achieved this functionality, but when I try to implement Web services in my app so that once all rows are selected the id of all rows will be available. The code that I have implemented is given below:

This is my `JSON` response

```
{
  "message" : "Quation List",
  "success" : "1",
  "quation_list" : [
    {
      "fk_customer_id" : "1",
      "total_price" : "1230",
      "margin" : "30",
      "freight" : "20",
      "created_date" : "2019-09-06 14:14:41",
      "id" : "1",
      "created_by" : "8",
      "quantity" : "2",
      "part_number" : "15"
    }
  ]
}
```

So for this `JSON`, I have created a model class for parsing as below

```
struct QuotationListModel {
    var id: String
    var quantity: String
    var margin: String
    var created_date: String
    var part_number: String
    var total_price: String
    var freight: String
    var fk_customer_id: String
}
```

up to this part, everything is perfect, My button click code for selecting all rows is given below

```
var isSelectAll = false //Global Variable

@IBAction func btnSelectAllTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if btnSelectAll.titleLabel?.text == "Select All"{
        self.isSelectAll = true
        self.btnSelectAll.setTitle("DeSelect All", for: .normal)
        self.btnSelectAll.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 119/255, green: 119/255, blue: 119/255, alpha: 1)
        self.tblListView.reloadData()
        self.btnShare.isHidden = false
    } else {
        self.isSelectAll = false
        btnSelectAll.setTitle("Select All", for: .normal)
        btnSelectAll.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 175/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)
        self.btnShare.isHidden = true
        self.tblListView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

and here is code for `cellForRowAt IndexPath`

```
if(isSelectAll==true) {
    cell.viewMain.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 210/255, green: 251/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    cell.imgView.isHidden = false
} else {
    cell.viewMain.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.imgView.isHidden = true
}
```

so with this code `SelectAll` `DeSelect All` work fine for me but how to get all rows id on Select All button click please help me

I got this below answer but in the link provided below, he used NSMutableArray`

[Refer the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32048696/11808059)

Comment: If you select all row on your button click then fetch all selected row ids from your array. Try this : `let arrSelectedIds = YOUR_ARRAY.map({ (quotation: QuotationListModel) -> String in quotation.id })`

Comment: That's nice, you can accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select all row on your button click then fetch all selected row ids from your array. Try this :

```
let arrSelectedIds = YOUR_ARRAY.map({ (quotation: QuotationListModel) -> String in quotation.id })
```