# The method selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:) doesn't call tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to set the default selected row by `selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)`. But the document said calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` message.

How to set the default selected row and call the `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`?

Comment: You can call yourself `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`.

Comment: duplicate please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I just have to call the `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You can call `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`

after `selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

In viewWillAppear() or after few milliseconds of viewDidLoad, call this:

```
tableView.selectRow(at: <IndexPath?>, animated: <Bool>, scrollPosition: <UITableViewScrollPosition>)
```

Share you full source code here, so can give you better suggestion.