# Programmatically call a tableView cell's .delete editingStyle

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I found a way to programmatically select a row in my tableView through using the `delegate` method like suggested in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40589905/3511695

Right now I have a `.delete` `editingStyle` option for each of my tableView's cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        // code that's called when user presses delete button
    }
```

How could I call this `delete` function programmatically? i.e. Simulate the user pressing the `delete` button? (Just like how I was able to programmatically simulate pressing a tableView cell)

I have an `alertController` in my `if (editingStyle == .delete) {}` that I need to have show up again, which is why I need to programmatically simulate the user pressing the Delete button in the UI rather than simply deleting the row.

Comment: The real answer is. Don't do this. You have have a model that you update. When you update the model, the view controller should automatically update the views. Don't treat your view as if it was a model. Use MVC or some other architecture and correctly partition your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is not `UITableViewDelegate` method, but `UITableViewDataSource` method.

This is not the best solution, but if you really want to do it like this, call this method on `dataSource` of your TableView and as parameters pass your TableView, editingStyle as `.delete` and certain `IndexPath`

```
tableView.dataSource?.tableView!(tableView, commit: .delete, forRowAt: indexPath)
```

---

Now what you should be doing:

You should put code from if statement in `commit` data source method to new method and then you should call this method here

```
if (editingStyle == .delete) {
    method()
}
```

and instead of calling `tableView.dataSource?...`

```
method()
```

Comment: I already have that code inside my `if (editingStyle == .delete) {}`. That just deletes the rows. I want to simulate the user pressing the `delete` button. (More is done in my code when the user presses the `delete` button than just deleting the row.)

Comment: @velkoon yes, so just call what I wrote above

Comment: I have an alert controller that comes up in my `if (editingStyle == .delete) {}` that will not appear if I simply do `yourTableView.deleteRows(at: [someIndexPath], with: .automatic)`. I need the `if (editingStyle == .delete) {}` to be programmatically executed so my alertController appears.

Comment: Perfect! I've got some more troubleshooting to do, but this is exactly what I needed, thank you

Comment: Don't do this. Never directly call a delegate or data source method. If you think this is correct then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Ah, of course, yes. Very easy to do it the correct way. I'm sure the information you provided originally will still prove resourceful to others too..